# How do I create a one-to-many relationship so that one blog post can have many categories

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building a CMS like WordPress. I would like to be able to assign multiple categories to a blog post.

My tables look as follows:

```
Article:
-id
-title
-author
-user_id
-date
-resource link
-content
-status
-featured_image

Categories:
-id
-name
```

I know how to design it so that a blog post can have one category but not many.

Comment: You need a further table (term for this is 'bridge table'). Columns `{Article-id, Category-id}` Key to be composite both columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could design your database like this.
This schema allows you to assign multiple categories and to add multiple images that you can track individually.

[image: Logical model of the SQL]

```
CREATE TABLE BlogPost
(
    blogPostNr INT NOT NULL,
    author CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    categoryNr INT NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    status CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    text VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    title CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    userId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT BlogPost_PK PRIMARY KEY(blogPostNr)
);

CREATE TABLE Image
(
    imageNr INT NOT NULL,
    description CHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    picture LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    source CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Image_PK PRIMARY KEY(imageNr)
);

CREATE TABLE BlogPostHasImage
(
    blogPostNr INT NOT NULL,
    imageNr INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT BlogPostHasImage_PK PRIMARY KEY(blogPostNr, imageNr)
);

CREATE TABLE Category
(
    categoryNr INT NOT NULL,
    categoryName CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Category_PK PRIMARY KEY(categoryNr)
);

ALTER TABLE BlogPost ADD CONSTRAINT BlogPost_FK FOREIGN KEY (categoryNr) REFERENCES Category (categoryNr) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE BlogPostHasImage ADD CONSTRAINT BlogPostHasImage_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (blogPostNr) REFERENCES BlogPost (blogPostNr) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE BlogPostHasImage ADD CONSTRAINT BlogPostHasImage_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (imageNr) REFERENCES Image (imageNr) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not 1:many, but many:many -- because also a Category can be associated with many Articles.

Have a 'mapping' table with 2 columns, `article_id` and `category_id`.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for tips on indexing such.